# SoC and computer architecture

Tags: cpu-architecture, soc

What is actually computer architecture and what is the difference between it and SoC..?? I tried reading through few articles but I couldn't get a proper difference between this two.

Comment: The question is rather broad... You could say that SoC is a sub group of computer (or rather CPU) architectures that focus on placing all the components on a single chip (to improve communication between them and to reduce manufacturing costs).

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing apples and oranges. Computer Architecture is a sub-field of computer science that deals mainly with the hardware on which applications are run. Various aspects studied as part of computer architecture are performance of digital circuits and logic, interconnection between components, coherence/consistency, power and area overheads etc. Software development is many-a-times driven by the underlining architecture for which the code is being written.

SoC (System-on-Chip) on the other hand is 'type' of system design where CPU, GPU, accelerators, and other peripheral modules (like ethernet, cellular) are all placed on a single chip (or piece of die). An alternative to SoC would be a design where the CPU is a separate die, the GPU is discrete (connected by PCI) and the peripherals are on a separate die which is connected to the CPU die using a bus. To put in other words, SoC is a way of placing components around in a given area. The computer architecture issues (CPU perf, power, network) for a SoC design would be different from the issues for a non-SoC platform.